# microsoft bot to intercept files posted in messages

Tags: botframework

I'm writing a bot installed in a Microsoft Teams channel.
It has to intercept files posted in messages and upload them to a remote location.
I'm posting a message and attach a file.

Unfortunately, in OnMessageActivityAsync, the activity does not contain the file.
Attachment is null.
Everything is working fine, I receive any kind of content, except the file.
What Am I missing? I seam to have read somewhere that files are accessible only on bots installed in personal chats?

```
 protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 {
     var teamsChannelId = turnContext.Activity.TeamsGetChannelId();
     var teamDetails = await TeamsInfo.GetTeamDetailsAsync(turnContext, turnContext.Activity.TeamsGetTeamInfo().Id, cancellationToken);
     string teamId = teamDetails.AadGroupId;
     await Dispatch(teamId, teamsChannelId,turnContext.Activity);
 }
```

[image]